# Prove the $f_1, f_2$ is a basis of linear subspace of solution of differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $p,q \in C(\mathbb{R}), L_{pq} = \{f \in C^2(\mathbb{R}):f^{(2)} + pf^{(1)} +q f = 0\} $
For each $(a,b)^T \in \mathbb{R}^2$ there is only one $f \in L_{pq}$ with $(f(0),f'(0)) = (a,b)$

1- Prove, that $L_{pq}$ is linear subspace of $C(\mathbb{R})$.
2- Prove the following: Let $f_1, f_2 \in L_{pq}$ and $(f_1(0),f'_1(0)) = (1,0)$ and  $(f_2(0),f'_2(0)) = (0,1)$ then $f_1,f_2$ is basis of $L_{pq}$.
3- Give a basis of $L_{pq}$ in the case $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} : p(x)=0$ and $q(x) =1$

I have already proved that $L_{pq}$ is a subspace of $C(\mathbb{R})$ (closed under addition and multiplication with scaler), but I can't understand the second question, would very much appreciate any help.

Comment: The second question should be read in the following manner. Suppose that you have two solutions $f_1$ and $f_2$ of your equation with such properties. Then you have to prove that **any** solution can be represented as linear combination of $f_1$ and $f_2$.